# Dynamically created ltng:require component results in 503

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, lightning-community, create-component

If I try and create a `ltng:require` component for a script dynamically, I get a 503 server error:

component.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <div>This component checks static resource loading on Init</div>
                         {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

componentController.js

```
({
doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
        "ltng:require",
        {
            "scripts": "/community/resource/loadMe.js"

        },
        function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newButton);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );
    }
}
})
```

Error Message

> GET https://customdomain-developer-edition.na53.force.com/community/resource/loadMe 503 (Service Unavailable)

However, If i add the component in the markup, it seems to load fine.

Working component.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.loadMe}"/>

    <div>This component checks static resource loading on Init</div>

    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

I am trying to check certain conditions when my page loads, and depending on x,y factors, I am trying to load a different script, should I attempt to achieve this using aura:if 's to conditionally load different static resources or should my current approach work?

Based on my comprehension of what a [503 status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is, my current approach should work, however, for some reason it wont process my request to load the static resource if I try to create it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the standard translation service for this:

```
    $A.createComponent(
    "ltng:require",
    {
        "scripts": $A.get("$Resource.loadMe")
    },
```

Also, note that your resource string was technically incorrect; the bare `/resource/filename` syntax does not normally include the file extension.

Comment: indeed, i would have expected a 404 if the string/filepath would have been incorrect. Thanks for the heads up.